# How can I plot a function to represent a string with a knot in it in R^3 in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a few different graphs in R^3, one being a string with a loop in in R^3 which I have managed to do.

The plot I am struggling on is how can I represent different types of knots (in closed intervals [0,1]) in a plot in R^3 by using functions?

This is as far as I have gotten in my attempt to try to produce a trefoil knot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}  
\addplot3[variable=t,mesh,domain=0:1]  
 ({(0.8*cos(deg(3*t)))/(1-(0.6)*sin(deg(2*t)))},{ (0.8*sin(deg(3*t)))/(1-(0.6)*sin(deg(2*t)))}, {(1.08*cos(deg(2*t)))/(1-0.6*sin(deg(2*t)))});  
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But clearly it does not do what I had pictured (produce a knot).

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Please read this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that